# Is it possible to restrict the connection duration per client on the router (say with OpenWRT)?

Tags: networking, wifi, access-point, openwrt

How to limit the connection duration per client per period (say, one MAC-address can connect only for 3 hours per week to the network).

Where could be defined such a rule? In the firewall?

So the rule should define not statically times (this is simple), when the client is allowed to access the network, but the duration of the connection per day/week/month, etc.

How/where to implement such rules? Is it possible to do so with OpenWRT/DD-WRT?

Comment: Not without WPA2-Enterprise and RADIUS accounting, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Take a look into any of the alternative firmwares that support captive portal (tomato shibby for example)